# Can I say this :$e^{{(294204)}^{1/11}}-{(294204)}^{1/11}$ integer number or almost integer?

Tags: approximation, integers

I have tried to get integers using exponential function , i have got this approximation:$e^{{(294204)}^{1/11}}-{(294204)}^{1/11}\sim 20 $ , Can I say this is integer or almost integer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my calculator $$e^{{(294204)}^{1/11}}-{(294204)}^{1/11}=19.99909959...$$ which is *not* an integer.

I think you've discovered that $${(294204)}^{1/11}=3.14159263...\approx\pi$$ and it is rather well-known that $$e^\pi-\pi\approx20$$